# Eloquent eager loading deep nested relation with "where" condition

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

is there a more elegant way to do what the code below does without use "foreach"?
I am trying to load answers from questions but only the answers that contains a direct relation with an Appointment

```php
public function show(Request $request, Patient $patient)
{
    $user = $request->user();

    $appointments = Appointment::with('forms.questions')
        ->where('patient_id', $patient->id)
        ->where('user_id', $user->id)
        ->get();

    foreach ($appointments as $appointment) {
        foreach ($appointment->forms as $form) {
            foreach ($form->questions as $question) {
                $question->load(['answers' => function ($q) use ($appointment) {
                    $q->where('appointment_id', $appointment->id);
                }]);
            }
        }
    }

    return view('patients.show', compact('patient', 'appointments'));
}
```

I tried with no luck

```php
public function show(Request $request, Patient $patient)
{
    $user = $request->user();

    $appointments = Appointment::with(['forms.questions.answers' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('answers.appointment_id', 'appointments.id')
    }])
        ->where('patient_id', $patient->id)
        ->where('user_id', $user->id)
        ->get();


    return view('patients.show', compact('patient', 'appointments'));
}
```

EDIT: Below are the relationships

- Form

  - questions (hasMany)
  - appointments (belongsToMany)
- Question

  - answers (hasMany)
- Answer

  - question (belongsTo)
  - appointment (belongsTo)
- Appointment

  - answers (hasMany)
  - forms (belongsToMany)
  - patient (hasOne)
  - user (hasOne)
- Patient

  - user (BelongsTo)
  - appointments (hasMany)
- User

  - appointments (hasMany)

A table called appointment_form is a pivot table for appointments and forms table.

Comment: Ahoy! Please [edit] to explain the relationships more thoroughly. Is there a one-to-many relationship between questions and answers? and also does an answer belong to an appointment, separately from through the question or using a belongsToThrough relationship? You could consider using the format from [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/268176/120114)

Comment: you can add a different relation or a scope within questions model or consider using a builder class instead. Re builder class, dont know the scale of your app - but, ask yourself a question - what will happen you need to  change `patient_id` to something different?

Comment: Why do answers belongTo appointments? Shouldn't it be just answer->question->form->appointment?

Answer (score 2):

The solution below comes after rethinking the actual implementation of the business logic.

Since one Appointment can have zero or many Answers, I do not need to relate Appointments with a Form.

All I have to do is only save Answers with the reference of Question and Appointment.

And on `appointments.show` when I need only the Forms (with Questions) that have Answers related with current Appointment just do:

```php
$fromAppointment = function ($builder) use ($appointment) {
    $builder->where('appointment_id', $appointment->id);
};

$forms = Form::whereHas('questions.answers', $fromAppointment)
    ->with(['questions.answers' => $fromAppointment])
    ->get();
```

And on `appointments.edit` when I need all the Forms even those that do not have Answers, all I need to do is:

```php
$forms = Form::with(['questions.options', 'questions.answers' => function ($builder) use ($appointment) {
    $builder->where('appointment_id', $appointment->id);
])
->get();
```

And the relationship between Appointments and Forms was dropped.